# Can't deploy heroku on Mac OS M1

Tags: heroku

I'm new on Heroku and trying to deploy my project here. After I typed this command in the terminal: curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh

and I also typed the administrative password correctly , I got this error message: unsupported arch: arm64

Answer (score 7):

The script does not support `arm64` (see line 40 pf the script).

The easier option is to install via brew

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

or download the [tarball](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#other-installation-methods) for macOS (if you still prefer doing it manually)

Comment: There is no tap name 'heroku' today.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [tarball macOS](https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-darwin-x64.tar.gz)

```
tar xvf heroku-darwin-x64.tar
sudo mv heroku /usr/local/lib
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s  /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku .
heroku --help
```

Apple Silicon Issues
If you’re getting the following error on a machine with an Apple M1 chip, you haven’t installed or declined to install [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861).
Bad CPU type in executable
Installing Rosetta 2 resolves this issue.
If you don’t want to install Rosetta 2 on your machine, you can install the Heroku npm package globally and use your own Node binary locally. Only v16 of Node has M1 ARM support and npm isn’t the recommended install method.
ref: [heroku install](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli?ref=hackernoon.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

This command doesn't work for me

```
==> Installing heroku from heroku/brew
Error: Your Xcode (14.0.1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 14.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

but there is no update in theApp Store.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, had to use npm.
npm install -g heroku

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
arch -arm64 brew install heroic
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
arch -arm64 brew install heroku
```

Comment: Warning: No available formula with the name "heroku".

Comment: Don't forget to tap the cask with `brew tap heroku/brew` first. At that point you can drop the `arch -arm64` and just `brew install heroku`